# Traducción de «"stray" x-rays»

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, terminología, ciencia

¿Cómo traducen "**stray X-rays**"? ¿Rayos X difusos? ¿Rayos X extraviados? ¿Rayos X perdidos?

Comment: Bienvenida, Teresa, a [Spanish.SE]. Nos encantaría ayudarte, pero para eso deberías ayudarnos tú un poquito. ¿Qué es exactamente "stray X-rays" en inglés? ¿Qué se conoce por ese término? Si nos das una definición exacta de "stray X-rays" en inglés, mejor será la ayuda que podamos darte. Al ser un término de uso científico, puede que la traducción no sea obvia. Por otro lado, si nos especificas en qué país quieres usar la traducción podremos minimizar la probabilidad de toparnos con diferencias regionales. Puedes [edit]ar la pregunta y añadir la información que falta.

Answer (score 3):

Creo haberla traducido siempre como "radiación parásita":

> **Stray radiation** is radiation that reaches the detector that is not in the desired wavelength range. ([Source](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=v2hvDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT185&dq=%22stray%20radiation%20is%22&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8x8CMgovmAhX2FbkGHb2ADD0Q6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22stray%20radiation%20is%22&f=false))
>
> **Radiación parásita** es cualquier radiación que llega al detector y que no posee una longitud de onda similar a la seleccionada. ([Fuente](http://repositorio.unac.edu.pe/bitstream/handle/UNAC/136/AnaZola_Tesis_tituloprofesional_2013.pdf?sequence=3&isAllowed=y))

Answer (score 1):

Refiriéndose a radiación innecesaria producida por un experimento en particular, hay quien dice *radiación espuria* o *radiación indeseada*, como en [este artículo (Figura 3.6)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/44373534_Propiedades_estructurales_y_vibracionales_del_MnGa2Se4_bajo_altas_presiones_y_temperaturas_Jesus_R_Marquina/figures?lo=1).

Refiriéndose en general a la radiación que hay en el ambiente proveniente de diversas fuentes desconocidas, se puede hablar de *radiación de fondo* para las fuentes naturales, o *[radiactividad artificial](https://www.revistaciencia.amc.edu.mx/images/revista/55_2/radiactividad_nuclear.pdf)* para las artificiales.